# How to determine if a machine is running Active Directory

Tags: windows-services, active-directory, registry, windows-server-2008

I would like to know from Java code if the machine that I'm on is running active directory or that it has active directory installed (e.g. service may be stopped). Is there a reliable registry key to inspect? This is specifically for Windows 2008.

I found info on the web that mentions HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSDTC\Security\DomainControllerState, but that value is 0 on my domain controller as well as on my normal windows 7 machine!?

Answer (score 1):

Is using the registry as means to determine if the AD service is running mandatory or can you use WMI instead? E.g. [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/)

```
String name = getWMIValue("Select * from Win32_Service WHERE State = 'Stopped'", "Name");
```

See also [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, more mandatory really, but easier to do. WMI might just work, thanks.